# What's the purpose of running VCS over SSH?

Tags: version-control, ssh

I'm not very familiar with SSH and *nix systems in general, so please forgive me for possibly stupid question.

What are the benefit and what is the exact purpose behind having one's VCS be tunneled (hope this is an appropriate term here) over an SSH connection? Is it speed? Or security? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security and that SSH is a standard transport protocol.  Also use of key authentication is common with SSH to provide password-less interaction with the VCS.  Speed is not a benefit as SSH encrypts transmissions and so time is taken doing the encrypt/decrypt.

Why pick a standard transport protocol?  Getting firewall clearance is more straight-forward, the VCS doesn't have to re-invent the wheel, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective answer, but here are three reasons that I would tunnel any application protocol over SSH, in order of importance:

1. Authentication and Authorization

   I don't have to maintain my own database of users, don't have to think about password encryption, don't have to give the sysadmins yet another thing to manage.
2. Connection management

   I can focus on my application-level communications, without worrying that I've created an exploitable security hole.
3. Admins are more likely to open well-known ports